# Reset count in GQL (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I'm having a hard time trying to reset my ID/Name column in my google app. Right now it's on 3002, yet there's only 1 other peice of data still in the DB. I'm not even certain how it decided on 300x over like 1,2,3...

I'm sure this is a simple problem for someone more SQL inclined than I am :).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you want to reset the number?

Comment: It's not that important...as you can see from the comment below, I was just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Generated IDs are guaranteed to be unique, but not sequential or contiguous. There's no facility for resetting the ID counters.

Comment: That sucks. Wonder why it jumped into the three and four thousands?

Comment: why does it suck?  how are you using the id?

Comment: I guess it doesn't suck...I just get annoyed when things aren't in perfect order (starting with 0 or 1). Thanks again. :)

Comment: It jumped because servers request IDs in chunks for efficiency. Sometimes a server restarts and its chunk of IDs gets discarded.